# Download to current directory

Tags: c++, winapi, urlmon

I want to download the file to current directory instead of "c://". How would that be done?

My code:

```
using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")

int main()
{
    cout << "downloading update";
    HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, _T("http://download.piriform.com/ccsetup233.exe"), _T("c://ccsetup233.exe"), 0, NULL);
    FreeConsole();
}
```

Comment: I believe that you just need to change "c://ccsetup233.exe" to "ccsetup233.exe", without the path name

Comment: Specify just the file name, without the path. `_T("ccsetup233.exe")`

Comment: Worked. Thank you.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but the path separator is a backslash on Windows. Instead of `"c://ccsetup233.exe"` you need to be using `"c:\\ccsetup233.exe"`. Note that some APIs will translate forward slashes to backslashes, but I wouldn't take any chances. Note also, that a forward slash does not need to be escaped in a string literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference for `URLDownloadToFile()` says this about the `szFileName` parameter (emphasis mine):

> A pointer to a string value containing the **name or full path** of the
>   file to create for the download. If szFileName includes a path, the
>   target directory must already exist.

If you pass only a file name instead of a full path, it will download to the current directory. This is not explicitly documented but it is the normal way how the Windows API works.

Though I wouldn't take any chances that the current directory at the time of the call to `URLDownloadToFile()` is the same as it was at the start of the program. Any code may have called `SetCurrentDirectory()` to change the current directory to something else.

To make the code more robust I would call `GetCurrentDirectory()` only once at the start of the program and store the path in a variable. Before calling `URLDownloadToFile()` I would append the filename to that path and pass the full path for the `szFileName` parameter.

On a side note, you should call `CoInitialize()` at the start and `CoUninitialize()` at the end of a program that uses `URLDownloadToFile()` because it is a COM API. You might get away without that but that would be pure luck and may cease to work in different Windows versions.